# ERROR: TypeError: in typeassert, expected VersionNumber, got a value of type Pkg.Types.VersionSpec

Tags: julia

I am currently setting up a CI job on GitHub actions using Julia 1.6. However, the CI is randomly erroring out when it tried to update the general Julia registry. I bumped the Julia version to 1.7 and it seemed to resolve the issue: https://github.com/JuliaLangSlack/StackOverflowBot/runs/6435769247?check_suite_focus=true

Full code: https://github.com/JuliaLangSlack/StackOverflowBot

Any suggestions as to why this might be happening on 1.6? There haven't been any breaking changes so it's weird that just increasing the version resolves the issue.